# Asp.net razor datetime validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a following code in my page:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PublishingEndDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublishingEndDate)
```

And input date format is `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm` but validation fails.
From where does the validation get the format, and can it be set globally in application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your property validation attribute to include the format above like so:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}")]
```